# Enable certsrv.msc windows server 2008 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ad-certificate-services

How to start the certsrv.msc? I need to create a cert to access to an active directory over SSL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`certsrv.msc` is only available on servers where `Active Directory Certificates Services` role is installed.

It is located in `C:\Windows\System32`

Go to :

1. Start
2. find and run `certsrv.msc`

Or

1. Run `Server Manager`
2. Expand `Roles`
3. Expand `Active Directory Certificates Services`

Comment: There's no `Active Directory Certificates Services` in my server manager only `Active Directory Domain Services` and inside `AD Users and computers` and `AD Sites and Services`

Comment: @Kuait You certainly have a CA server somewhere. To find it try this : On your DC Server open a cmd prompt, then run `certutil -CA`. From the output check `CAPropDNSName = server.domain.local`. This is your CA Server.